# How to remove missing values (NA) when uniting columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I am trying to unite 5 columns into one new column using the Unite function. However, all rows contain lots of NA values, creating variables that look like

```
Mother|NA|NA|NA|NA
NA|NA|Father|Mother|NA
Mother|Father|NA|Stepmother|NA
```

I've tried to unite them using this code:

```
df2 <- df %>%
unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", remove = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But that gives me the following error:
Error: `TRUE` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector

I've also looked on the forum, and found that possibly the na.rm function of unite is not active?

Here is some data to recreate my dataset

```
Name <- c('Paul', 'Edward', 'Mary')
Postalcode <- c('4732', '9045', '3476')
Parent <- c('Mother', 'NA', 'Mother')
Parent2 <- c('NA', 'NA', 'Father')
Parent3 <- c('NA', 'Father', 'NA')
Parent4 <- c('NA', 'Mother', 'Stepmother')
Parent5 <- c('NA', 'NA', 'NA')

df <- data.frame(Name, Postalcode, Parent, Parent2, Parent3, Parent4, Parent5)
```

Would love to know how to unite my columns without NA's.

UPDATE:

I've now updated the tidyr package and I added "na = c("", "NA")" to my read_csv command.

Now the

```
df2 <- df %>%
unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", remove = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Command works, however for some reasons the NA at the end of the value stays. Now my columns look like this:

```
Mother|NA
Father|Mother|NA
Mother|Father|Stepmother|NA
Does anyone know what went wrong now?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got couple of problems,

1) the `NA`s are not reals `NA`'s (Check `is.na(df$Parent2)`)

2) Your columns are factors

While constructing the dataframe use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
df <- data.frame(Name, Postalcode, Parent, Parent2, Parent3, Parent4, 
                 Parent5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and then replace `NA` and use `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  na_if('NA') %>%
  tidyr::unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE)

#    Name Postalcode              Parent_full
#1   Paul       4732                   Mother
#2 Edward       9045            Father|Mother
#3   Mary       3476 Mother|Father|Stepmother
```

If the data is already loaded, we can change them by using `mutate_if`

```
df %>%  
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 na_if('NA') %>%
 tidyr::unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: My actual dataset was not created with the data.frame() function, but loaded from csv. Should I transform the columns that are factors? And if so, what should I transfrom them into? Numeric?

Comment: @JolienJansen Convert them to character using `mutate_if`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @JolienJansen If you're loading from CSV, then `read.csv` should make any cell values of "NA" and blank cells into NA automatically. If your NA values are written otherwise, for example as "na", you could just load it in with `read.csv("file.csv", na.strings = "na")`, or whatever your NA values are written as in the CSV.

Comment: @JolienJansen Ddi you try `df %>%  
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 na_if('NA') %>%
 unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I did, it kind of worked, most NA's disappeared from in the new column, except the NA at the end of every value. 
Now it looks like: Mother|NA Father|Mother|NA Mother|Father|Stepmother|NA

Comment: So I tried the same code on 2 similar datasets (different years), and there it worked perfectly. Everything in these datasets is the same, and the code is also the same but tweaked to fit the datasets. In only 1 of the files, the NA's on the end keep appearing.

Comment: @JolienJansen If the columns are characters and those are real `NA` values it should work ideally. Otherwise a work-around is to remove `NA` values using `regex`, `df %>%  
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  na_if('NA') %>%
  unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Parent_full = sub("NA$", "", Parent_full))`

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem here is that you haven't updated to `tidyr` 1.0 yet. That error message is the best that the previous version can do with the input `na.rm = TRUE`, since that argument didn't exist before. It thinks you're giving it a named argument as part of the `...`.

Specifically, just run `install.packages("tidyr")` and it should work. You might need to restart R first, so `tidyr` isn't currently loaded.

If your missing values are `"NA"` strings, then, as Ronak pointed out, you need to use `na_if()` on them first. It's strange to me because your initial code chunk makes it look like those are proper NAs, due to the red highlighting. But then your reprex code has `'NA'` values which would definitely be strings. Anyway, you say you're reading in from CSV, so, it would be cleaner and quicker to run the CSV-reading code so as to read NAs in properly with an `na` argument or the like.

*Response to Edit:* That does seem like a bug, that NAs at the end of the united string don't get properly removed. Well, anyway, the fix is easy, and probably better than anything else we could do:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at("Parent_full", . %>%
              str_remove("(^|\\|)NA$") %>%
              na_if(""))
```

This ensures two things: 1) that the letters "NA" at the end of a string are only removed if they're there because of the `unite()`, with a pipe (if anything) in front of them; and 2) if there's no non-missing values on a line here, then the value will be a proper NA rather than `"NA"`, `""`, or what have you, which I assume is what you want.

*Update*: I've found that the bug applies to any column that contains nothing but NAs, i.e. `na.rm = TRUE` only removes NAs from columns that have at least one non-missing value. I've filed a bug report: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/765

Given this, though, the optimal solution is probably just to remove any columns that are all NA beforehand. If this is production code, though, then that gets real tricky, since you have to specify the `unite()` so as to not break if any or even all of the columns to be united are dropped by that prior step.

*Update 2*: As a response to the bug report pointed out, the issue is actually that that all-missing column is logicals. So that makes the optimal solution: read in such columns as character, or coerce them to character before uniting. Full reprex for that:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Name <- c('Paul', 'Edward', 'Mary')
Postalcode <- c('4732', '9045', '3476')
Parent <- c('Mother', NA, 'Mother')
Parent2 <- c(NA, NA, 'Father')
Parent3 <- c(NA, 'Father', NA)
Parent4 <- c(NA, 'Mother', 'Stepmother')
Parent5 <- c(NA, NA, NA)

(df <- data.frame(Name, Postalcode, Parent, Parent2, Parent3, Parent4, Parent5))
#>     Name Postalcode Parent Parent2 Parent3    Parent4 Parent5
#> 1   Paul       4732 Mother    <NA>    <NA>       <NA>      NA
#> 2 Edward       9045   <NA>    <NA>  Father     Mother      NA
#> 3   Mary       3476 Mother  Father    <NA> Stepmother      NA

(df2 <- df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Parent:Parent5), as.character) %>% 
    unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", na.rm = TRUE))
#>     Name Postalcode              Parent_full
#> 1   Paul       4732                   Mother
#> 2 Edward       9045            Father|Mother
#> 3   Mary       3476 Mother|Father|Stepmother
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`unite()` (and `na.rm = TRUE`) only works for character columns (as far as I can tell). This isn't made clear in the help docs.

For factors, it also returns the integer code rather than the factor level - something to watch out for.

---

Numeric: Doesn't remove NAs:

```
df <- data.frame("to.combine1" = c(NA, 1, 3),
                 "to.combine2" = c(2, NA, 3))

sapply(df, class) #not functional, just illustrative
#> to.combine1 to.combine2 
#>  "numeric"   "numeric"           

unite(df, "combined", to.combine1:to.combine2, sep="_", na.rm = TRUE)
#>   combined
#> 1     NA_2
#> 2     1_NA
#> 3      3_3
```

Factor: Doesn't remove NAs and uses integer code rather than level:

```
df <- data.frame("to.combine1" = as.character(c(NA, 1, "a")),
           "to.combine2" = as.character(c(2, NA, "a")),
           stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

sapply(df, class) #not functional, just illustrative
#> to.combine1 to.combine2 
#>    "factor"    "factor" 

unite(df, "combined", to.combine1:to.combine2, sep="_", na.rm = TRUE)
#>   combined
#>1     NA_1
#>2     1_NA
#>3      2_2
```

Character: Expected behaviour

```
df <- data.frame("to.combine1" = as.character(c(NA, 1, "a")),
                 "to.combine2" = as.character(c(2, NA, "a")),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sapply(df, class) #not functional, just illustrative
#>to.combine1 to.combine2 
#>"character" "character" 

unite(df, "combined", to.combine1:to.combine2, sep="_", na.rm = TRUE)
#>   combined
#> 1        2
#> 2        1
#> 3      a_a
```

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow. While you provide interesting information about `unite()`, you don't actually answer the question. Thus, it is likely that it will be removed. Rather, you could post this information as a comment. Or maybe it is more appropriate for a different question (that deals with numerics).

Comment: Thanks @hplieninger, good to be here. I agree, initially I tried to leave it as a comment but don't have enough rep to do so. Point well taken though, thank you, if it is deleted then so be it!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the NAs later with something like this

```
df %>%
  unite(Parent_full, Parent:Parent5, sep = "|", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Parent_full = gsub("(?<![a-zA-Z])NA\\||\\|NA(?![a-zA-Z])|\\|NA$", '', Parent_full, perl = T))
```

```
    Name Postalcode              Parent_full
1   Paul       4732                   Mother
2 Edward       9045            Father|Mother
3   Mary       3476 Mother|Father|Stepmother
```

It replaces `NA|` not preceded by a letter or `|NA` not followed by a letter or `|NA` at the end of the string, with an empty string

Comment: Gotta be careful with this, though, since there's the off-chance that some string in the data will begin or end with `NA`. If one of the relative codes here happened to be `NANA` (all uppercase), as in the nickname for a grandmother, this would lop off the first and/or last `NA` letters. It might also help with this approach to use `^` and `$` which match the start and the end of the string, respectively. Lastly, there's lookahead and lookbehind to restrict the match without removing more than you want to.

Comment: That's a good point. I believe it can be accounted for with the following regex `"(?<![a-zA-Z])NA\\||\\|NA(?![a-zA-Z])|\\|NA$"` I'll update my answer.